# Is it possible to store a Tween 80 stock solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, safety, surfactants

I am making a stock solution of Tween 80 (0.05 % w/v) and each experiment requires just 15 ml of the stock solution. Is it possible to make a large batch (about 100 ml) and store it somewhere? If so, what should I look out for when storage?

Comment: Please note that nonconforming units such as "% w/v" should not be used in science and technology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Sigma Aldrich/Merck product information for "TWEEN® 80 solution"](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/deepweb/assets/sigmaaldrich/product/documents/154/550/p6224pis.pdf) states the following:

> **Storage/Stability**
>
> Aqueous solutions of polysorbates as well as the neat liquid will
> undergo autoxidation over time, with changes being catalyzed by light,
> increased temperature, and copper sulfate.[9]
>
> Solutions are reasonably stable at 2 - 8 °C for short periods. For
> special applications, storage under argon or nitrogen may be
> preferred.
>
> [9.] Donbrow, M., et al., Autoxidation of polysorbates. [J. Pharm.
> Sci., **67**, 1676-1681 (1978)](https://doi.org/10.1002/jps.2600671211).

While this is not a very specific time span, it clearly indicates that TWEEN solutions are not long-term stable. If you need to store it, then in a fridge, protected from light and preferentially under an inert atmosphere for a few days max.

Comment: If you do this be sure to leave the date the solution was prepared on the bottle.